# AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionDenied After Enabling Microphone via iPhone Settings App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avaudiosession

I am using this code to test if the user has enabled Microphone permissions:

```
- (void)checkAudioPermissions {
    switch ([[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] recordPermission]) {
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionGranted:
            // Audio permission already granted.
            [self initAudioSession];
            break;
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionDenied:
            // User previously denied the iOS Microphone Permissions
            [self audioDeniedAlert];
            break;
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionUndetermined:
            // Initial state before a user has made any choice
            [self preRequestAudioRecordingPermission];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

If I disable the Microphone for my app, the `AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionDenied` case is triggered and the user is shown a `UIAlertView`, which allows the user to open the Settings App.

If I open the Settings App, enable the Microphone, tap the `< Back to App` button in the top-left of the screen, and then re-run the `switch`... it skips `AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionGranted` and runs the `AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionDenied` case again.

If I kill and restart the app, then the `AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionGranted` case is triggered.

Is there something I need to do when I re-run the `switch` so that `AVAudioSessionRecordPermissionGranted` is triggered without having to restart the app?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: strange - changing the microphone permission _kills_ the app, which refreshes `recordPermission`. You're not seeing that?

Comment: Yes now I see it is killing and restarting the app. I swear that yesterday it was just taking me back to the previous screen without killing the app - maybe because my device was attached to Xcode? Thanks for pointing this out, though it will take some work to get the user back to the correct screen ...